# Multiprocessing two indefinitely running functions while sharing data

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, queue, simultaneous

I'm new with multiprocessing in Python. I need three functions to run simultaneously while also doing stuff to the same "multiprocessing queues" and exchanging them. I'm getting thousands of frames in second from a camera so I need these functions to run in parallel to operate fast and not lose any data. My main problem is that when I make any changes to the contents of this queues in any of these functions, the other functions doesn't realize them in real time. All functions need to run indefinitely meaning all of them has infinite loops inside them.  For example if I put "1" into queue1 in func1, I want func2 to realize this change in the next loop.
My pseudo code looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

** func1 is getting data from a camera continuously**

def func1 (queue1,data):
    while True:
        **doing some stuff with data**
        if (condition)          
           queue1.put(data)  
        **I never break the loop**

def func2(queue1, queue2):
    while True:
        data = queue1.get()
        **doing some stuff with data**
        if (condition)          
           queue2.put(data)
        **I never break the loop**


def func3(queue2):
    while True:
        data = queue2.get()
        **doing some stuff with data**
        
        **I never break the loop**


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    queue1 = mp.Queue()
    queue2 = mp.Queue()
    p1 = mp.Process(target=func1,args=(queue1,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = mp.Process(target=func2, args=(queue1,queue2))
    p2.start()
    p3 = mp.Process(target=func3, args=(queue2,))
    p3.start()
```

For example, func1 might put something to queue1 and func2  gets that item from queue1 and then works on it. Depending on the result func2 puts something into queue2 and func3 operates on queue2. I thought mp.Queue() is a shared memory but when changes are made to the queue inside a function the other functions doesn't get updated.
I'm working on Windows 10 and Python 3.10.
Thank u!

Comment: The code doesn't look wrong to me... when you say "when I make any changes to the contents of this queues in any of these functions, the other functions doesn't realize them in real time"... what happens? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: If I add "1" to queue1 in func1 , func2 doesnt recognize this and still thinks queue1 is empty.

Comment: Are you sure that that's what's happening? Maybe the problem is in a faulty `condition`? Try printing something as soon as func2 gets the data (right below the `queue.get()` line) and see if the function is actually receiving the data but is not passing it on due to some other bug. Also, I hope you are joining the `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` processes at the end using `.join()`

Comment: Since processes have infinite loops they never end. So join should be pointless I think. Also I'm printing the length of the queue inside other functions to check any updates. The length of the queue is not changing even though the other functions are putting new elements into it.

Comment: You need to use `.join()` otherwise your **main** process will not wait for the other processes to complete. Also, printing the length of the queue is extremely unreliable (due to multiple consumers/producers), especially in this case, since the moment something gets on the queue it will be taken off by the other processes

Comment: @Charchit As long as the child processes created by the main process are not *daemon* processes, they will continue to run independently of the main process. Strictly speaking the main process would only need to call `join` on the child processes if it needs to wait for their completion before continuing with further processing.

Comment: @Booboo I think you are right, thanks for pointing it out.